# Rails maintain_test_schema! not working in Rails 5.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to keep my test database schema current with my development/production database. I have read that including:

`ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`

in my `test_helper.rb` file should accomplish this. However, investigating the source code led me to this "conflict":

```
def maintain_test_schema! # :nodoc:
  if ActiveRecord::Base.maintain_test_schema
    suppress_messages { load_schema_if_pending! }  # <<<--- this leads to...
  end
end
```

```
def load_schema_if_pending!
  if Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration? || !Base.connection.migration_context.any_migrations?
    # Roundtrip to Rake to allow plugins to hook into database initialization.
    root = defined?(ENGINE_ROOT) ? ENGINE_ROOT : Rails.root
    FileUtils.cd(root) do
      current_config = Base.connection_config
      Base.clear_all_connections!
      system("bin/rails db:test:prepare")  # <<<--- this command doesn't get introduced until Rails 6
      # Establish a new connection, the old database may be gone (db:test:prepare uses purge)
      Base.establish_connection(current_config)
    end
    check_pending!
  end
end
```

We are running Rails 5.2.6, but the `bin/rails db:test:prepare` command doesn't appear to be introduced until Rails 6. I'm unsure how this command could be in our app considering we are not on Rails 6, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish the same task (automatically keeping the test database schema up-to-date).